# Update false positive rules on sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, updates, rules, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

I have a problem with my sonarqube comunity edition in web rule:S4645. It is similar to this false positive

[https://community.sonarsource.com/t/false-positive-web-s4645-a-script-was-found-without-a-relating-opening-script-tag/75374][1]

According to what I have read this problem is already fixed

I would like to know what I have to do to update that rule or if I have to update the whole sonarqube to a newer version?

Thanks